# Python Regex Confusion with =

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to replace to capture the `\n\n` in the contents below:

However, when I try:

```
re.search('=============== K # 1 ===============(.*)=====================',
    '=============== K # 1 ===============\n\n==================================================')
```

I get back `None`.

If I do:

```
re.search('=============== K # 1 ===============(.*)',
    '=============== K # 1 ===============\n\n==================================================')
```

I will get a match.

Why are the additional `===...` preventing me from matching?

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `.` doesn't match newlines. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character except a newline. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.

Thus, to fix this, add the `re.DOTALL` flag:

```
re.search('=============== K # 1 ===============(.*)=====================',
          '=============== K # 1 ===============\n\n==================================================',
          re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: While this will work, the match it returns will include some number of `=`s in addition to the `\n\n` he is trying to match, and if applied to a larger string, will likely match even more.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to match the newlines, try

```
re.search('=============== K # 1 ===============(\n*)=====================',
'=============== K # 1 ===============\n\n==================================================')
```

As `*` is greedy, if you are using `.`, it will match as many of the `=`s as it can after the `\n`s as well as just the `\n`s if you use re.DOTALL to allow it to match `\n`. As you apparently only want to match the \n\n, this isn't what you want.

Note that you can make this more compact by specifying the number of `=`s you want to match:

```
re.search('={15} K # 1 ={15}(\n*)={21}',
'=============== K # 1 ===============\n\n==================================================')
```

To illustrate the problem with using `.`:

```
In [7]: s = '=============== K # 1 ===============\n\n=================================================='

In [8]: re.search('={15} K # 1 ={15}(.*)={21}', s, re.DOTALL).groups()
Out[8]: ('\n\n=============================',)

In [9]: re.search('={15} K # 1 ={15}(\n*)={21}', s).groups()
Out[9]: ('\n\n',)
```

Alternatively, you could use `[^=]` to match any non-'=' or `\s` to match any whitespace.